# クロスコンパイル環境構築でglibcのmakeが失敗する

Tags: gcc

### 目的

下記リンク先の手順を元に、クロスコンパイル環境構築を再現したい。

[各種アーキテクチャのクロスコンパイラ環境を構築する](http://inaz2.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/12/01/204201)

### 環境

- Vagrant box: ubuntu/xenial64
- provisioner: ansible_localによりgccをソースからコンパイルするのに必要なg++, bison, flex, texinfoを追加インストール済み
- Vagrantfile

  ```ruby
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
      config.ssh.insert_key = false
      config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
      config.vm.box_check_update = false
      config.vm.synced_folder "C:\\（Vagrantfileの場所）\\synced_folder", "/vagrant_data"

      config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = "2048"
      end

      config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
          ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
          ansible.verbose = true
      end
    end
  ```
- playbook.yml

  ```
    - hosts: all
      become: yes
      user: ubuntu
      tasks:
        - name: Install packages
          apt: pkg={{item}} force=yes update_cache=yes
          with_items:
            # to build compiler
            - g++
            - bison
            - flex
            - texinfo
  ```

### 実行したこと

```
C:\（Vagrantfileの場所）
λ vagrant up

ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$sudo apt-get update
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$sudo apt-get upgrade
```

手動でglibcだけのmakeが成功するか検証しようとすると

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/build-glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu$ ../glibc-2.22/configure --prefix=/opt/cross/aarch64-linux-gnu --build=$MACHTYPE --host=aarch64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --with-headers=/opt/cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/include --disable-multilib --disable-nls libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes
略
checking installed Linux kernel header files... missing or too old!
configure: error: GNU libc requires kernel header files from
Linux 2.6.32 or later to be installed before configuring.
```

ということで、エラーの検証は前提として、binutils-2.25、linux-3.16のkernel headers、gcc-5.2.0(ライブラリを除く)のmake installまで完了する必要がありそうである。（少なくともLinux kernel headerはmake install済みである必要がありそう）

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo ./download.sh
```

download.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

BINUTILS_VERSION=binutils-2.25
LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION=linux-3.16
GCC_VERSION=gcc-5.2.0
GLIBC_VERSION=glibc-2.22

wget -nc http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/binutils/$BINUTILS_VERSION.tar.gz
wget -nc https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/$LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION.tar.xz
wget -nc http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/gcc/$GCC_VERSION/$GCC_VERSION.tar.gz
wget -nc http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/glibc/$GLIBC_VERSION.tar.xz

for f in *.tar*; do
    tar xfk $f
done

cd $GCC_VERSION
./contrib/download_prerequisites # windowsとの共有ディレクトリ/vagrant_dataで実行していると、この行でシンボリックリンクが張られるときに管理権限がなくて失敗するので、スクリプトはその以外の場所で実行する
cd ..
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/cross$ sudo mkdir -p /opt/cross
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/cross$ sudo chown ubuntu /opt/cross
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo ./build.sh
```

build.sh（エラーが出る直前まで）

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

PREFIX=/opt/cross

PARALLEL_MAKE=-j4
CONFIGURATION_OPTIONS="--disable-multilib --disable-nls"

BINUTILS_VERSION=binutils-2.25
LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION=linux-3.16
GCC_VERSION=gcc-5.2.0
GLIBC_VERSION=glibc-2.22

TERMCAP_VERSION=termcap-1.3.1
GDB_VERSION=gdb-7.3.1

mkdir -p $PREFIX
chown ubuntu $PREFIX

build() {
    local TARGET="$1"
    local LINUX_ARCH="$2"

    # Step 1. Binutils
    mkdir -p build-binutils-$TARGET
    cd build-binutils-$TARGET
    ../$BINUTILS_VERSION/configure --prefix=$PREFIX --target=$TARGET $CONFIGURATION_OPTIONS
    make $PARALLEL_MAKE
    make install
    cd ..

    # Step 2. Linux Kernel Headers
    cd $LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION
    make ARCH=$LINUX_ARCH INSTALL_HDR_PATH=$PREFIX/$TARGET headers_install
    cd ..

    # Step 3. C/C++ Compilers
    mkdir -p build-gcc-$TARGET
    cd build-gcc-$TARGET
    ../$GCC_VERSION/configure --prefix=$PREFIX --target=$TARGET --enable-languages=c,c++ $CONFIGURATION_OPTIONS
    make $PARALLEL_MAKE gcc_cv_libc_provides_ssp=yes all-gcc
    make install-gcc
    cd ..

    # Step 4. Standard C Library Headers and Startup Files
    mkdir -p build-glibc-$TARGET
    cd build-glibc-$TARGET
    ../$GLIBC_VERSION/configure --prefix=$PREFIX/$TARGET --build=$MACHTYPE --host=$TARGET --target=$TARGET --with-headers=$PREFIX/$TARGET/include $CONFIGURATION_OPTIONS libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes
    make install-bootstrap-headers=yes install-headers
    # 今回エラーが出るmake $PARALLEL_MAKE csu/subdir_lib
}

build aarch64-linux-gnu arm64
```

ここまで実行した上で、上記スクリプト中の `make $PARALLEL_MAKE csu/subdir_lib`、つまり

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/cross/build-glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu$ sudo make -j4 csu/subdir_lib
```

が失敗するので、 **これを成功させたい** というのが今回の質問です。

実行したときのエラーログは
http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/#IDComment1016903189
のvenkateshさんと似ている。以下エラーログです。

```
ここまで文字数制限のため省略
In file included from ../sysdeps/aarch64/nptl/tls.h:47:0,
                 from ../include/errno.h:27,
                 from check_fds.c:18:
check_fds.c: In function ‘check_one_fd’:
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:203:17: error: invalid register name for ‘_x0’
   register long _x0 asm ("x0");
                 ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:206:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_0’
   LOAD_ARGS_0 ()    \
   ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:210:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_1’
   LOAD_ARGS_1 (x0)    \
   ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:214:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_2’
   LOAD_ARGS_2 (x0, x1)    \
   ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:218:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_3’
   LOAD_ARGS_3 (x0, x1, x2)   \
   ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:179:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_4’
        LOAD_ARGS_##nr (args)     \
        ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:189:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW’
  INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW(SYS_ify(name), err, nr, args)
  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:164:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL’
   ({ unsigned long _sys_result = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (name, , nr, args); \
                                  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/not-cancel.h:36:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘INLINE_SYSCALL’
    INLINE_SYSCALL (openat, 4, AT_FDCWD, name, flags, mode)
    ^
check_fds.c:64:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘open_not_cancel’
       int nullfd = open_not_cancel (name, mode, 0);
                    ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:211:17: error: invalid register name for ‘_x1’
   register long _x1 asm ("x1") = _x1tmp;
                 ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:214:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_2’
   LOAD_ARGS_2 (x0, x1)    \
   ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:218:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_3’
   LOAD_ARGS_3 (x0, x1, x2)   \
   ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:179:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_4’
        LOAD_ARGS_##nr (args)     \
        ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:189:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW’
  INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW(SYS_ify(name), err, nr, args)
  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:164:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL’
   ({ unsigned long _sys_result = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (name, , nr, args); \
                                  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/not-cancel.h:36:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘INLINE_SYSCALL’
    INLINE_SYSCALL (openat, 4, AT_FDCWD, name, flags, mode)
    ^
check_fds.c:64:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘open_not_cancel’
       int nullfd = open_not_cancel (name, mode, 0);
                    ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:215:17: error: invalid register name for ‘_x2’
   register long _x2 asm ("x2") = _x2tmp;
                 ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:218:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_3’
   LOAD_ARGS_3 (x0, x1, x2)   \
   ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:179:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_4’
        LOAD_ARGS_##nr (args)     \
        ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:189:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW’
  INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW(SYS_ify(name), err, nr, args)
  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:164:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL’
   ({ unsigned long _sys_result = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (name, , nr, args); \
                                  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/not-cancel.h:36:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘INLINE_SYSCALL’
    INLINE_SYSCALL (openat, 4, AT_FDCWD, name, flags, mode)
    ^
check_fds.c:64:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘open_not_cancel’
       int nullfd = open_not_cancel (name, mode, 0);
                    ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:219:17: error: invalid register name for ‘_x3’
   register long _x3 asm ("x3") = _x3tmp;
                 ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:179:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_4’
        LOAD_ARGS_##nr (args)     \
        ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:189:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW’
  INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW(SYS_ify(name), err, nr, args)
  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:164:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL’
   ({ unsigned long _sys_result = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (name, , nr, args); \
                                  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/not-cancel.h:36:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘INLINE_SYSCALL’
    INLINE_SYSCALL (openat, 4, AT_FDCWD, name, flags, mode)
    ^
check_fds.c:64:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘open_not_cancel’
       int nullfd = open_not_cancel (name, mode, 0);
                    ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:180:22: error: invalid register name for ‘_x8’
        register long _x8 asm ("x8") = (name);   \
                      ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:189:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW’
  INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW(SYS_ify(name), err, nr, args)
  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:164:34: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL’
   ({ unsigned long _sys_result = INTERNAL_SYSCALL (name, , nr, args); \
                                  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/not-cancel.h:36:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘INLINE_SYSCALL’
    INLINE_SYSCALL (openat, 4, AT_FDCWD, name, flags, mode)
    ^
check_fds.c:64:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘open_not_cancel’
       int nullfd = open_not_cancel (name, mode, 0);
                    ^
../o-iterator.mk:9: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/build-glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu/csu/check_fds.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/build-glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu/csu/check_fds.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ../sysdeps/aarch64/nptl/tls.h:47:0,
                 from ../include/link.h:45,
                 from ../include/dlfcn.h:4,
                 from ../sysdeps/generic/ldsodefs.h:32,
                 from ../sysdeps/aarch64/ldsodefs.h:46,
                 from ../sysdeps/gnu/ldsodefs.h:46,
                 from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ldsodefs.h:22,
                 from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/ldsodefs.h:22,
                 from libc-start.c:22:
libc-start.c: In function ‘__libc_start_main’:
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:203:17: error: invalid register name for ‘_x0’
   register long _x0 asm ("x0");
                 ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:206:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_0’
   LOAD_ARGS_0 ()    \
   ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:179:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘LOAD_ARGS_1’
        LOAD_ARGS_##nr (args)     \
        ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:189:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW’
  INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW(SYS_ify(name), err, nr, args)
  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/exit-thread.h:36:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL’
       INTERNAL_SYSCALL (exit, err, 1, 0);
       ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:180:22: error: invalid register name for ‘_x8’
        register long _x8 asm ("x8") = (name);   \
                      ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/sysdep.h:189:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW’
  INTERNAL_SYSCALL_RAW(SYS_ify(name), err, nr, args)
  ^
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/exit-thread.h:36:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘INTERNAL_SYSCALL’
       INTERNAL_SYSCALL (exit, err, 1, 0);
       ^
In file included from ../include/link.h:45:0,
                 from ../include/dlfcn.h:4,
                 from ../sysdeps/generic/ldsodefs.h:32,
                 from ../sysdeps/aarch64/ldsodefs.h:46,
                 from ../sysdeps/gnu/ldsodefs.h:46,
                 from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/ldsodefs.h:22,
                 from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/aarch64/ldsodefs.h:22,
                 from libc-start.c:22:
../sysdeps/aarch64/nptl/tls.h:105:21: error: __builtin_thread_pointer is not supported on this target
  ((struct pthread *)__builtin_thread_pointer () - 1)
                     ^
libc-start.c:279:30: note: in expansion of macro ‘THREAD_SELF’
       struct pthread *self = THREAD_SELF;
                              ^
../o-iterator.mk:9: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/build-glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu/csu/libc-start.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/build-glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu/csu/libc-start.o] Error 1
In file included from ../include/errno.h:27:0,
                 from ../csu/libc-tls.c:19,
                 from ../sysdeps/aarch64/libc-tls.c:19:
../sysdeps/aarch64/libc-tls.c: In function ‘__tls_get_addr’:
../sysdeps/aarch64/nptl/tls.h:101:19: error: __builtin_thread_pointer is not supported on this target
   (((tcbhead_t *) __builtin_thread_pointer ())->dtv)
                   ^
../sysdeps/aarch64/libc-tls.c:30:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘THREAD_DTV’
   dtv_t *dtv = THREAD_DTV ();
                ^
/home/ubuntu/build-glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu/sysd-rules:1347: recipe for target '/home/ubuntu/build-glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu/csu/libc-tls.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/build-glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu/csu/libc-tls.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/glibc-2.22/csu'
Makefile:213: recipe for target 'csu/subdir_lib' failed
make[1]: *** [csu/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/glibc-2.22'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'csu/subdir_lib' failed
make: *** [csu/subdir_lib] Error 2
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~/build-glibc-aarch64-linux-gnu$
```

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ この質問で解決したいことは何ですか？　現状単にエラーメッセージが書かれているだけです。また、ご自身の環境についても記載があると答えやすいと思います（リンクされているブログにも書かれているような、OS、gcc、dockerなどの情報のことです）。再現できるように、具体的にどういう手順で何をしたのかもあると良いかもしれません。自分の質問は「編集」から自由に加筆できますので、お願いします。

Comment: 特に今回の場合、[参考になさったページ](http://preshing.com/20141119/how-to-build-a-gcc-cross-compiler/)の Required Packages でダウンロードしてきた諸々のバージョンが関係してきそうです。

Comment: 参考: 自分で試してみたところ、現在最新のバージョンに揃えた以下の環境下でエラー無くビルドできました（[ログ](https://gist.github.com/nekketsuuu/38edb7a5210b096e55949fd019ff850e)）。 ホスト側は Ubuntu 16.04 (on Docker 17.03.1-ce), gcc 5.4.0, g++ 5.4.0, gmake 4.1, gawk 4.1.3, perl v5.22.1, bash 4.3.48(1)。ビルドされたものは、binutils 2.28, gcc 7.1.0, linux 4.11.7, glibc 2.25, mpfr 3.1.5, gmp 6.1.1, mpc 1.0.3, isl 0.16.1, cloog 0.18.1。

Comment: 件のページには "Dealing with Build Errors" として「必要なパッケージやツールを忘れている」「ビルドの順番が違う」「正しい手順で行ったが、ビルドされる側の config が壊れている」を挙げています。このあたりはエスパーしないとどこが原因か分からない気がするので、是非どのような手順でビルドしたのかをご記載ください。

Comment: 参考: こちらでは、i0z0m さんの環境とソースのバージョンを合わせてもビルドが成功してしまいました……。ただしこちらは Docker 上での結果です。こちら[ログです](https://gist.github.com/nekketsuuu/062c6eb9f8350e69c4094172d1a3b00f)。　／　どこかでスクリプトの細かいところ（PREFIXなど）を間違っていたりしませんか？　たとえば質問中のスクリプトは `../glibc-2.22/configure` の行で変なところに空白文字があります（コピペミスだと思いますが……）。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ビルドを始める前に、クロスコンパイルするターゲット用のバイナリが置かれる場所を `$PATH` に追加してください。

具体的には、今回の場合、

```sh
PATH="${PREFIX}/bin:${PATH}"
```

を行ってください。おそらくこれをしておかないと、たとえば gcc をビルドする際にクロスコンパイル用の gcc (今回の場合 `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc`) を見つけてくれません。

他の方法として、 gcc のビルドオプションにおいて "Cross-Compiler-Specific Options" に分類されているオプションを使ってパスを指定してあげることによっても解決できるかもしれません。これらのオプションについては[このマニュアル](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html)をご参照ください。

Comment: [お試し頂いたログ](https://gist.github.com/nekketsuuu/062c6eb9f8350e69c4094172d1a3b00f)とこの回答に準拠して更新した（と自分は思っている）場合の結果が[こちら](https://gist.github.com/i0z0m/3bdab117999ac2f9342b76e9327313f5/c4090f630b78e7129e8c13aa1af6ea73555e9f30)です。build.shの52行目に（ビルドをする前に）PATH=$PREFIX/bin:$PATHを設定し、[目的URL](http://inaz2.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/12/01/204201)のStep3のmakeでgcc_cv_libc_provides_ssp=yesオプションを消したのが、現在私が自覚している差分です。エラーログの上部が解消していますが、下部は似た感じの結果に思えます。

Comment: `build.sh` 内に `export PATH=...` を書き、`build.sh` を実行した後に手動で `make -j4 csu/subdir_lib` されたということでしたら、`build.sh` の中で変更されているのはサブシェル内の環境変数であるため、親のシェルでの `$PATH` は変更されていないのではないでしょうか？ `make -j4 csu/subdir_lib` する前に `echo $PATH` などとして確かめてみてください。

Comment: 上記のコメントを参考に改良し成功した（と思われる）結果が[こちら](https://gist.github.com/i0z0m/3bdab117999ac2f9342b76e9327313f5/0180dbed295d1b2ea7d5079986fa9cd27f848d35)です。root権限で手動で#export PATH=/opt/cross/bin:$PATH を行いました。サブシェルの性質？上、スクリプトで設定するわけにはいかないのでしょうか？

Comment: 僕の知る限り、親シェル側で設定しない限り子シェルの設定は親に引き継がれないはずです。シェルスクリプト内で行った変更を親にも引き継ぎたい場合は `source build.sh` または `. build.sh` を使う方法がありますが、これをすると `$PATH` 以外の環境変数も親に引き継がれてしまいます。 参考: ["Can a shell script set environment variables of the calling shell?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/496702/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

Comment: inaz2さんのように `/usr/local/bin` にインストールするなど、元から標準的にPATHが通っている場所にインストールすることにすれば、 `$PATH` への追加は避けられます。

Comment: Dockerでも再現しました https://hub.docker.com/r/i0z0m/ubuntu-crossbuild/

Comment: 後進のためにnekketsuuu氏の自己回答質問[PATHとは何ですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37237/path-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)を貼っておきます

Comment: 全く需要がありませんが，[Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/i0z0m/ubuntu-crossbuild/)を削除したので，[Dockerfileを置いたレポジトリ](https://github.com/i0z0m/ubuntu-crossbuild)を公開しておきます．