# glibcのビルド時のCommand not foundエラー

Tags: linux, makefile

glibcを `make install` しようとすると `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: Command not found`
とエラーが出てしまいます。
コマンド `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` 自体はパスが通っており、ターミナルで `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` の実行は可能です。

makeがパスをうまく認識してくれないのですが対処法を教えて頂きたいです。

Comment: エラーはできるだけ省略せずに全文を載せてください (前後の行にも重要なメッセージが含まれている可能性があります)。 / "パスは通っている" とありますが、`which` コマンドなどを使ってフルパスを確認して質問に追記してみてください。

Comment: [クロスコンパイル環境構築でglibcのmakeが失敗する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/36010/16894)

Comment: エラーなのですが、```make[1]: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: Command not found```となります。

Comment: ```which```コマンドの結果は```/usr/local/aarch64-tools/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc```でした